# If $a_n$ converges to $A$ and a is a non-empty set, show that $4A^2=A^2+4+4/(A^2)$

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Consider the example of the sequence defined recursively by $$a_{n+1} = \frac12\left(a_n+\frac{2}{a_n}\right)$$ for $n\geq1$. By easy algebra,$$4a^2_{n+1} = a^2_n+4+\frac{4}{a^2_n}$$
>
> 1. Suppose $\{a_n\}\to A \neq 0 $. Show that $$4A^2 = A^2 + 4 + \frac{4}{aA^2}$$
> 2. By algebra, this simplifies to a quartic equation in $A$, which is actually a quadratic equation in $A^2$. Find the two possible values of $A^2$. $\square$

I've already done part 2 of the question, I just don't know how to start the proof for the first part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $a_n \to A$ then $a_{n+1} \to A$, ${1 \over a_n} \to {1 \over A}$   and then the equation $a_{n+1} = {1 \over 2} ( a_n + {1 \over a_n})$ shows that
$A = {1 \over 2} ( A + {1 \over A})$. Squaring yields the desired result.